# Apache Virtual Hosts DocumentRoot path

Tags: apache

```
[1] DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
[2] DocumentRoot /var/www/example_com/public_html
```

Which one option is it more preferable? Dotted or underscored?

And once file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` is changed, is it needed to re-run also `$ sudo a2ensite example.com.conf` ? Or change itself is enough? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each option is ok, it's as you want. For my part, on my dedicated server, I'll use example.com syntax.

When you run `$ sudo a2ensite example.com.conf` for the first time, a symlink is created from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`.

You can change this file at two location, because it's the same file.
If you want to disable your vhost, you should run `$ sudo a2dissite example.com.conf`